# equivalent to interface method implementation when classes must not be modified

Tags: c#, performance, dynamic, interface

Assume we have an interface `IInterface` and several classes `Class1`, ..., `ClassN` implementing this interface.

I need a method `CheckSomething` for all implementers of that interface. One way is to make `CheckSomething` a method of `IInterface` and implement it for all classes:

```
interface IInterface { bool CheckSomething(string arg); }
class Class1 : IInterface { public bool CheckSomething(string arg) { ... } }
...
class ClassN : IInterface { public bool CheckSomething(string arg) { ... } }
```

There might be reasons to keep the `CheckSomething` methods out of the code of the classes (e.g. the we cannot modify the code of the classes; e.g. the method `CheckSomething` does not belong to the class semantic-wise).

To still get the same behaviour, we can use extension methods:

```
static class MyExtensionMethods
{
    public static CheckSomething(this Class1 c, string arg) { ... }
    ...
    public static CheckSomething(this ClassN c, string arg) { ... }

    public static CheckSomething(this IInterface i, string arg) // option 1
    {
        dynamic dynI = i;
        return i.CheckSomething(arg);
    }
}
```

Regarding `dynamic` everyone warns that it will give performance penalties, so...

- ... is the extension method version slower than the interface method version? How much? And why?
- ... is there any other way to get the same behaviour and the same performance as in the interface method version - without modifying the code of the classes?

Comment: Is the implementation of CheckSomething class specific or is the implementation equal for all classes (implementers of the interface)?

Comment: I don't know the answer to your performance question, but in terms of implementation you're looking for the Decorator pattern aren't you? Create a decorator which defines the `CheckSomething` and use this to decorate just the classes where you want to check something. http://www.dofactory.com/net/decorator-design-pattern

Comment: @Fabian The implementation is class-specific.

Comment: @getsetcode: I think this should be an answer instead of a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem to have reference to the implementations for the classes you may go for a more or less ugly switch case. I do not know about performance though.

```
public static class MyExtensionMethods
{
    public static CheckSomething(this IInterface i, string arg) // option 1
    {
        switch (i)
        {
             case i is Class1 class1:
                  // class specific implementation (maybe in a separate method)
             ...
        }
    }
}
```